# Deploy windows phone 7 app in the device

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created an windows phone 7 app. I need to test it in the device. I have got Nokia Lumia 710(OS: Mango7.5) and I need to deploy the app I created in this device and test it. What is the step by step procedure I need to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should have a Microsoft [Apphub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) developer account, which you need to [developer unlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769508%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) the device.(Using the "Windows phone developer Registration" tool from your windows phone SDK)

After developer unlocking the device, in visual studio, selecting the debugging target as "windows Phone device" instead of "Emulator" and start debugging(or deploying your app). Also make sure you have the latest version of [Zune](http://www.zune.net/en-GB/) is installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your apps on your device, the "legal way" (microsoft way) you must:

1) Make sure you have registered as a developer on the AppHub and have paid your subscription.

2) Install the latest version of the Zune software.

2) Plug in your phone via USB and let Windows setup the drivers.

3) Lunch the Zune software and make sure that it picks up your device.  The Zune software is the gateway to the device it will always need to be running for any software on your PC to be able to talk to the phone – including Visual Studio when you are debugging.

4) Next you need to unlock your device using the Windows Phone Developer Registration Tool which can be found in the Windows Phone Developer Tools folder of your Start Menu.

got this text form http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/unlocking-your-wp7-device-for-app-development/

Comment: When you start deploying the app with visual studio, the phone must have an unlocked screen. But visual studio will thell you when this is not done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Unbelievable as it seems...**

Unfortunately you need to have a [AppHub account (at US$99)](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/faq) if you want to be allowed to upload code to your phone.

The only way round this is I know of is either to have purchased a [ChevronWP7 Token (no longer available)](http://lassic.tiktok.biz/search.asp?srchAthOrBib=sangha&EventID=runauckland&Edition=2011r5&pbSearch=quick%20search) and upgrade it to free AppHub account. Or to a have [dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) account - which also lets you have a free AppHub account.

1. [How do I unlock a device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202924%28VS.92%29.aspx)?

> **Windows Phone devices can be unlocked for development and testing**
>   **using an active account**. Accounts are limited to a certain number of
>   Device Unlocks and Apps per Device based on the account type.
>
> For Individual and Company accounts:
>
> ```
> 3 device unblocks
>
> 10 apps per device
> ```
>
> For Student accounts:
>
> ```
> 1 device unlock
>
> 10 apps per device
> ```